# $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{i}{z^2-3z+1 }$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Calculate** : $\int_{|z|=1}\frac{i}{z^2-3z+1 }$

---

I tried to use the Res theorem at infinity, but my answer was incorrect.

My attempt :

$f(z)=\frac{i}{z^2-3z+1 }$, $Res(f,\infty)=Res(\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z}),0)$

$\frac{1}{z^2}f(\frac{1}{z})=\frac{i}{1-3z+z^2}$

and we get the $0$  is a removable singularity so the $Res(f,\infty)=0$, but my answer should be $2/\sqrt5\pi$

I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Could you please explain why you have used the residue theorem at  $\infty$? Far more natural to me is solving $z^{2}-3z+1=0$ and then check whether the zeroes lie inside $C=\{|z|<1\}$

Comment: Because the zeros are in $C$

Comment: @PetrosK Is this Madaras mangekyou?

Comment: One root actual not both

Comment: @vitamind haha yees it is!

Comment: @AndréArmatowski i think easier to calculate the Res at $\infty$

Comment: I am really confused, I don't get why this isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

When integrating such (rational) functions in complex analysis, a good first step is always to factor the denominator. This way, you will get:

$$\frac{i}{z^2-3z+1} = \frac{i}{\left(z - \left(\frac{3}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)\left(z-\left(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)\right)} $$

You can see know that the function has two simple poles, of which only one is inside the unit disk, namely $z_0 = \frac{3}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

You can compute that the Residue is

$$ \operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = - \frac{i}{\sqrt{5}},$$

and then conclude with the Residue theorem that the integral you are looking for is equal to
$$2\pi i \operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = 2 \pi i -\frac{i}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\pi.$$

Edit: It seems that in order to use the Residue theorem at infinity, all singular points must lie inside the contour, which is not the case here, so that's the reason why there are different results.

Comment: The OP probably knows how to calculate this integral the way you did. He explicitly asked for the residue at infinity.

Comment: that's  true, I don't know why this method doesn't work when it's should give the same number.

Comment: I read it differently, as in "I tried using the residue at infinity because it seems easier" so I feel my answer is useful in showing that not going via the Residue at infinity is actually not difficult. But if I misread the question, I am sorry.

Comment: It's ok its probably my fault because i didn't explain it, thanks for answering thought.

Comment: Sure no problem. I never came across Residues at infinity yet, but a quick google search seems to indicate that you can use this calculation only if all the singularities of your function lie inside of your contour (which is not the case here). So this might be the reason why the approach with the Residue at infinity doesn't work here.

Comment: Ok so that's my mistake, I thought I could use it and in cases like that, thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to help, I learned something new myself :)

Comment: If you think of the circle on the Riemann sphere, then there's a pole inside the circle, and one outside.  There's a removable singularity at $\infty$, but since the residue there is $0$, it doesn't matter.  You can consider the contour as being "centered at $\infty", but then you will have to take the other pole into account.  You end up doing basically the same calculation either way.